# In a Triangle the value a/b+b/c+c/a equal to? Given that..

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, triangles, self-learning

r<sub>i</sub>=Exradius of triangle(i=1,2,3) respectively of the sides a,b,c

Exradius=Intersection of Exterior angle bisectors

Given r<sub>1</sub>=2r<sub>2</sub>=3r<sub>3</sub>

To find value of 
$$\frac{a}b+\frac{b}c+\frac{c}a$$

My Work till now

> > $5b=a+5c$
> >     
> > $2a=b+2c$
> >     
> > $3a=3b+c$
> >         
> >  by the use of the formula $$r_1=\frac{Area}{s-a}$$
> >     $$s=semiperimeter=\frac{a+b+c}2$$
> >     and similarly for $r_2$and $r_3$ and then canceling area I obtained these relations now unable to calculate further!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By your work we obtain $b=\frac{4}{5}a$ and $c=\frac{3}{5}a$, which gives
$$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}=\frac{5}{4}+\frac{4}{3}+\frac{3}{5}=\frac{191}{60}.$$$$

Answer (score 0):

From $$5b=a+5c\\2a=b+2c$$
we get $$10b-10c=2a=b+2c\implies 9b=12c\implies \frac{b}{c}=\frac43$$

Calculate the other fractions similarly.